# How add custom content HighCharts PDF export?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am generating a graph and html table with graph related info in a collapsible div.

Now the problem is I need to add the div content to my PDF export and not just the Graph, I see that there is a chart.exportDivElements but I could not find a related sample on how to use it.

Anybody has an idea about this? or an alternate to export highchart and a specific div to PDF via javascript?

Comment: Please familiar with http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$add-data-table

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have already seen this, the problem is I don't want to add the datatable to chart in the UI, I am using a collapsible Div to show the data table. I need it be in a different div

Comment: chart.exportDivElements does this export different div elements to PDF? can you give me a sample of a reference document for this?

Comment: @SebastianBochan this is the live page http://fintrack.logicwork.in/loan/LoanCaculator.aspx  We need to export the div at the bottom that is shown on clicking show statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the export server and saved the svg file (did away with the convert to jpg/png code as was not needed) to the server and used tcpdf to generate PDF with svg and required content, it was a bit hard to understand how to export server worked by got my head around and worked very well.

Comment: How can i implement the export server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The export server exports the chart SVG, not any arbitrary html content of the page. A possible solution is to the alter the export server and introduce an extra POST parameter 'customHtml'. In the phantomJS script you have to detect if the parameter is set and write the tablecontent to the page before it is rendered.